# Is there a version of the divine-hiddenness problem based specifically on the cognitive side of schizophrenia treatment?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, psychology, atheism, mysticism, mental-illness

Although to my knowledge [mystical psychosis "by itself"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystical_psychosis) is not a DSM listing, it is similar to symptoms of schizophrenia-spectrum disorders, symptoms like delusions of reference and grandeur (depending on the underlying delusions about the source of references and grandiosity). But so my question is then whether schizophrenia-spectrum sufferers (like myself) pose a kind of [philosophical divine-hiddenness problem](https://iep.utm.edu/divine-hiddenness-argument-against-gods-existence/) in that it is recommended to us, in the course of our treatment, that we try to avoid or block cognitive states that represent to us as if we are communicating with divine beings, are being guided by a divine plan, etc.? **If it is unhealthful of us to respond to apparent signs and omens and the like, and we know this health problem more than we know that God exists, then is God virtue-theoretically (so to say Aristotelianism-wise) to be hidden from us?** Or, we *ought to* resist belief in God as such?

We would not end up, then, as *nonresistant* nonbelievers. But our resistance would not be wrong, it would be expected, morally even (insofar as moral health is a combination of emotional and psychological health, say, again in an Aristotelian vein...). **Is this another form of the divine hiddenness problem, or is it a different, if related, such problem?**

Comment: The article you linked discusses non-philosophical forms of the problem at the end, including theological problem of divine hiddenness, where it says:"Consider, for example, responses that aim to propose a good for the sake of which God would be willing to hide. These would plausibly also be relevant to the theological problem." It may be in some way "unhealthy" for God's presence to be too overt not just to schizophrenia-spectrum sufferers but to creatures more broadly (because of the Icarus effect, say, or subversion of free will), and that would be a response.

Comment: You have to believe in order to know. This is the existence of truth beyond reason. The divine secrecy arguments in the link are not reliable. To me, this is a transdeterministic and deterministic issue. The web provides a different perspective on reality.

Comment: The mystical psychosis article is very interesting! It basically describes what I call a Neo experience. Many people have had abrupt changes of view due to stress or depression. Whether the results end up being enlightenment or not probably depends on to what degree the experience is actually 'psychotic'. Think of the movie A Beautiful Mind.

Comment: @ScottRowe I believe that a number of Christian philosophers — I'm thinking Plantiga, William Craig, maybe even Augusine — have argued that doubt is an integral part of the religious experience and process that is not available to non believers. Put differently, the modern notion that faith tautologically equals blind faith is a fiction that has little to do with real lived religion. Come to think of it 'doubting' Thomas is very much an apostle!

Comment: Perhaps you are asking to apply agnotology to schizophrenics: (p=>q)V(p<=q)=(p<=>q). Your question is very provocative. Don't be so weak as to want or not want God from others. That doesn't make you more than the hero of the day. In fact, it would be better to seek help from a specialist for symptoms that you cannot answer, because the subject comes into psychology. Psychology, on the other hand, is not accepted in every country where it is a branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, your gifts have a price, I see. From a person on one spectrum to another, the ought question, if one has some knowledge and belief in psychotherapy, hinges upon an intersection of the [therapeutic principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychotherapy) at play (there are at least a dozen major schools of therapy such as CBT, family systems therapy, feminist, psychoanalysis, Christian, existentialist, etc.) and the your model of the world, in this case one that seemingly seems predisposed to contemplate the [Hiddenness of God (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/divine-hiddenness/). From the article:

> “Divine hiddenness”, as the phrase suggests, refers, most fundamentally, to the hiddenness of God, i.e., the alleged fact that God is hidden, absent, or silent. In religious literature, there is a long history of **expressions of annoyance, anxiety, and despair** over divine hiddenness, so understood. For example, ancient Hebrew texts lament God’s failure to show up in experience or to show proper regard for God’s people or some particular person, and two Christian Gospels portray Jesus, in his cry of dereliction on the cross, as experiencing abandonment by God, whom he regarded as “Abba, Father”, an experience shared by many mystics, saints, and ordinary folk of all theistic traditions, described at its worst as “the dark night of the soul”. Understood in this way, divine hiddenness poses an existential problem for those who have such experiences. (emphasis mine)

You ask:

> Is this another form of the divine hiddenness problem, or is it a different, if related, such problem?

**If the philosophical tradition is about *expressions of annoyance, anxiety, and despair*, then it is an inevitable cosequence that there are both logical and psychological dimensions to the problem.** But on the psychological dimension, I suggest any good answer depends on your therapeutic stance. As far as research, I did come across this:

[Did Christianity lead to schizophrenia? Psychosis, psychology and self reference (NIH)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4107833/)

There seems to be a body of literature on schizophrenia and communicating with God. WP has an article on the topic entitled ["Religion and Schizophrenia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_and_schizophrenia). From WP:

> The relationship between religion and schizophrenia is of particular interest to psychiatrists because of the similarities between religious experiences and psychotic episodes; religious experiences often involve auditory and/or visual phenomena, and those with schizophrenia commonly report hallucinations and delusions that may resemble the events found within a religious experience.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychotherapy) In general, religion has been found to have "both a protective and a risk increasing effect" for schizophrenia.[2](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/divine-hiddenness/)

As a compulsive atheist, I can't possible related, but I'll share that my therapeutic preferences begins with [CBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy) to encourage it as a therapeutic stance. From WP:

> Cognitive behavioral therapy (CBT) is a psycho-social intervention[1](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/divine-hiddenness/) that aims to reduce symptoms of various mental health conditions, primarily depression and anxiety disorders.[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy) Cognitive behavioral therapy is one of the most effective means of treatment for substance abuse and co-occurring mental health disorders.[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_theology) CBT focuses on challenging and changing cognitive distortions (such as thoughts, beliefs, and attitudes) and their associated behaviors to improve emotional regulation[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion) and develop personal coping strategies that target solving current problems.

Given that divine hiddenness seems to be logical and philosophical approach to responding to "**expressions of annoyance, anxiety, and despair** (as per SEP), then clearly one attempt can be to do the theology. But from a CBT clinical perspective, the question is, is the model you have of the world suffering from distortions? That provokes the sticky question of whether your belief in God is a product of distorted reasoning or not. Here then, you have to decide whether there is sufficient empirical and rational support for the existence of God. If there is, then you are back to your philosophical pursuit. If your metaphysics obviates the need of God in your ontology, then you are in another problem space entirely.

In the former case, if you decide to resolve your question philosophically, finding experts in a religious tradition is your best path. Perhaps that is the Vatican and [natural theology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_theology). If, on the other hand, you reject God from your ontology, then an exploration of [cognitive distortions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion) and [fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy) is warranted. In either case, the additional knowledge you accumulate can help you with developing [coping mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coping) for unwanted thoughts and feelings. In both cases, finding someone with whom you have a good [therapeutic relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therapeutic_relationship) is pivotal (at least in accordance with modern psychological research).

Comment: On a personal note, it is absolutely difficult to find good therapeutic resources when one's model of the world of is far more sophisticated than one's therapist. That's because there's a tendency, in my experience, to desire to have the therapist capable of engaging in both the psychological AND the philosophical dimension. Needless to say, there are few people who have expertise in both areas.

Comment: Edited to include link to religion-schizophrenia article.

Comment: Mystical Psychosis doesn't seem to directly refer to communicating with God, especially via verbal thought. It seems quite in a different direction.

Comment: I favor CBT for philosophical reasons, and here is where I see the issue arising the most: if practicing CBT means reinterpreting things that seem like divine communications (of whatever stripe) so as to efface that seeming, then how can God reveal Itself in good faith to a schizophrenic such practitioner? For we will have a reason to engage in such reinterpretation, to hide God from ourselves; and so why would God have made the world in that way if it would supposedly be the greatest good to have a meaningful relationship with God? As if schizophrenia is a mark of damnation, even...

Comment: Well, when phrased as articulate as that, it seems then you've invented a new dimension to the Problem of Evil, since the purported claim to damnation is now predicated not JUST on the suffering such anxiety and despair that the Hiddenness brings but is COMPOUNDED by the additional dilemma of questioning one's vulnerability to distortion and sanity that arises from the schizophrenia. I'm a Camusian absurdist so I only deal with the pointlessness of life, but then I am not struggling with deciphering the intentions of my maker and the question of why It might burden me such struggles as yours.

Comment: As you suffer, you have my empathy. Namaste.

Comment: @ScottRowe Maybe. My metaphysics blinds me to such distinctions.

Comment: @KristianBerry There is always the issue of sorting out messages of God from messages of the devil. Perhaps this is a stronger instance of that? "*The best students get the hardest tests.*"

Comment: I should note that my sympathy to evidentialism does mean that if I have had to suppress "evidence of God" for myself, then I am in the position of unstable nonbelief rather than unstable belief. At any rate, the article about schizophrenia and Christianity is extremely interesting and alongside the references to CBT, it makes this answer helpful in resolving my issue (as confirmation of something in the back of my mind, no less).

Comment: @KristianBerry Indeed. That tug in your heart between empirical evidence and rational insistence, I believe to be a rather universal experience. I think Buddhism explores that tension best in terms of the Eight Fold path (not that I'm a Buddhist, mind you) in the difference between [Right View and Right Thinking](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/20880/what-is-the-difference-between-right-thinking-and-right-view). But no one except you can get you to reconcile them. I think it's possible to reconcile them in terms of Abrahamic theology if one accepts a position resembling...

Comment: [Christian atheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_atheism) where one can invest oneself fully in the theological message if one simply concedes that literal supernaturalism must give way to some post-supernaturalism view of God.

Comment: There is in the mind a fundamental tension between the supernaturalism of God and existential declaration applied in physicalism complemented by methodological naturalism. Such a tension must be brought to the surface in some form, and some resolution to the paradox must be invented to quiet the mind and sooth the soul. That's been my experience, anyway, where logic is a useful form of self-torture.

Comment: Good luck, and keep on trucking!